# Swift extract an Int, Float or Double value from a String (type-conversion)

Tags: string, swift, floating-point, int, double

Please could you help me here? I need to understand how to convert a String into an Int, Float or Double! This problem occurs when I'm trying to get the value from an UITextField and need this type of conversion!

I used to do it like this:

```
var myValue : Float = myTextField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue
```

but since Xcode 6 beta 6 it doesn't seem to work anymore!

I've tried also like this:

```
var str = "3.14"

// Conversion from StringValue to an Int
var intValue : Int = str.toInt()!

// Other converstion from StringValue to an Int
var intOtherValue : Int = Int(str)

// Converstion from StringValue to a Float
var floatValue : Float = str.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue

// Converstion from StringValue to a Double
var doubleValue : Double = Double(str)
```

Please help me or tell me where I can find the answer! Many thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Convert `String` to `NSString` and Use convenience methods:

```
var str = "3.1"
```

*To Int*

`var intValue : Int = NSString(string: str).integerValue`    // 3

*To Float*

`var floatValue : Float = NSString(string: str).floatValue` // 3.09999990463257

*To Double*

`var doubleValue : Double = NSString(string: str).doubleValue` // 3.1

---

*Reference*

```
var doubleValue: Double { get }
var floatValue: Float { get }
var intValue: Int32 { get }
@availability(OSX, introduced=10.5)
var integerValue: Int { get }
@availability(OSX, introduced=10.5)
var longLongValue: Int64 { get }
@availability(OSX, introduced=10.5)
```

Comment: You can cast the string to `NSString` instead of using an `NSString` constructor:  `var floatValue = (str as NSString).floatValue`.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
Int(string:String)
Double(string:String)
Float(string:String)
```

Which return an optional which is nil if it fails to parse the string.
For example:

```
var num = 0.0
if let unwrappedNum = Double("5.0") {
    num = unwrappedNum
} else {
    print("Error converting to Double")
}
```

Of course you can force unwrap if you are sure:

```
var foo = Double("5.0")!
```

### Extending String

If you are doing this in more than a few places, and want error handling to be handled the same everywhere then you may want to extend `String` with conversion methods:

For example:

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double {
        if let unwrappedNum = Double(self) {
            return unwrappedNum
        } else {
            // Handle a bad number
            print("Error converting \"" + self + "\" to Double")
            return 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

and then to use it:

```
let str = "4.9"
var num = str.toDouble()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public extension String {
    public func toFloat() -> Float? {
        return Float.init(self)
    }

    public func toDouble() -> Double? {
        return Double.init(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var holdTextFieldToStringValue = myTextField.text

//convert from string to Int

var holdIntValue = holdTextFieldToStringValue.toInt()!

//convert from string to Double

var holdDoubleValue = Double((holdTextFieldToStringValue as NSString).doubleValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let strValue = "14.03"

let result = (strValue as NSString).floatValue
```